# JavaScript, csv to json, split is not a function

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm trying to converte a csv local file to json and send it to an API.

But I have a problem with each function that I've found around.

I pick the csv file from event target like this

```
const csvAsJson = this.csvJSON(event.target.files[0])
```

Then in `csvJSON` function I have this:

```js
csvJSON = csv => {
    console.log(csv)
    var lines=csv.split("\n");
    // more code...
```

But I get an error at the `split` "csv.split is not a function".

In the `console.log(csv)` I got this:

```
File {name: "my file name.csv", lastModified: 1578504279032, lastModifiedDate: Wed Jan 08 2020 14:24:39 GMT-0300 (hora de verano de Chile), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8809, …}
name: "my file name.csv"
lastModified: 1578504279032
lastModifiedDate: Wed Jan 08 2020 14:24:39 GMT-0300 (hora de verano de Chile) {}
webkitRelativePath: ""
size: 8809
type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
__proto__: File
```

How should I use the split in a csv that is a file? I don't get it.

Comment: `event.target.files[0]` gives you the file object, not a string containing the contents of a file.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez — `event.target.files[0]` implies they are working a browser, not in Node.js. The duplicate covers how to read a file there.